# How to Resolve Compilation Errors for Zed Code Editor in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm compiling Zed Code Editor on Parrot OS and encountered a compilation error.

```
cargo run
   Compiling git2 v0.15.0
   Compiling reqwest v0.11.20
   Compiling live_kit_server v0.1.0 (/home/lilo/Program_Files/zed-0.124.7/crates/live_kit_server)
   Compiling live_kit_client v0.1.0 (/home/lilo/Program_Files/zed-0.124.7/crates/live_kit_client)
   Compiling procinfo v0.1.0 (https://github.com/zed-industries/wezterm?rev=0c13436f4fa8b126f46dd4a20106419b41666897#0c13436f)
   Compiling hound v3.5.0
   Compiling block v0.1.6
   Compiling ignore v0.4.20
error: failed to run custom build command for `live_kit_server v0.1.0 (/home/lilo/Program_Files/zed-0.124.7/crates/live_kit_server)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/lilo/Program_Files/zed-0.124.7/target/debug/build/live_kit_server-063323342ee20cc4/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at crates/live_kit_server/build.rs:4:10:
  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: "protoc failed: Could not make proto path relative: protocol/livekit_room.proto: No such file or directory\n" }
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

i tried to re-install  live_kit_server crate with cargo add but it didn't work also i tried the latest zed release

Comment: Read Zed's [README](https://github.com/zed-industries/zed). It mentions at the top that Zed only supports macOS. So you'll likely not be able to easily build the whole IDE for Linux

Comment: I notice that [`crates/live_kit_server/protocol` is a submodule](https://github.com/zed-industries/zed/tree/01e5e4224a3630e5bbd38462f63bc5487048fbd6/crates/live_kit_server). Did you do the [submodule initialization step listed in the build instructions](https://github.com/zed-industries/zed/blob/01e5e4224a3630e5bbd38462f63bc5487048fbd6/docs/src/developing_zed__building_zed_linux.md#repository) of `git submodule update --init --recursive`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the zed/crates/live_kit_server/protocol folder.
Mine was empty, it helped me to add this to the folder: https://github.com/livekit/protocol/tree/8645a138fb2ea72c4dab13e739b1f3c9ea29ac84